# Loading icon (progress) while logging into FTP in Android application

Tags: java, android, ftp, android-asynctask

How can I get a loading icon (like a small circle running rund) while I am logging into a FTP server in an Android application? I know that there is a progress bar in the `AsyncTask`, but  want to grey out the `MainView (MainActivity)` and display a loading icon as long as the login takes place.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the Progress "icon" to be shown as a Dialog (a smaller screen over your Activity) you can use `ProgressDialog`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

To use it:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this); 
pd.setTitle(title);
pd.setMessage(message);
pd.show();

...

pd.dismiss(); //Use it when the task is over
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

If you just want your layout to be seen like it's deactivated you can use the alpha property (opacity). For example, in an application where I want a layout to be seen darker than usual I use:

```
AlphaAnimation alphaDeselected = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.25F);
alphaDeselected.setDuration(0);
view.startAnimation(alphaDeselected);
```

Of course, the view will be seen darker if the background is dark.

**EDIT: How to apply it.**

I usually show the ProgressDialog right before starting the AsyncTask.

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(this); // I declared pd as a global variable to access it from AsyncTask
pd.setTitle(title);
pd.setMessage(message);
pd.show();
mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
```

Then I dismiss the ProgressDialog when the AsyncTask finishes or is canceled:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        pd.dismiss();

        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        pd.dismiss();

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question: How can I add this to an existing AsyncTask?